# Building a slide out feature box similar to expedia

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to build a slide out feature box on my site (similar to expedia) that animates after 2 seconds, stays visible for a few seconds and than hides away again. I would then like to make that appear once more with different text the second time around. I've tried making this play with checking the position of the element, but to no avail.

HTML:

```
<div class="viewer">
    <span class="top">Others Are Viewing This Deal</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
if ($('.viewer').position().left === -280) {
    $('.viewer').delay(2000).animate({left: '0'}, 1000, 'linear');
    $('.dealViewers .top').prepend(randomViews + " ");
}
else {
    $('.viewer').delay(4000).animate({ left: '-280'}, 1000, 'linear');
}
```

Comment: I hope that "randomViews" variable isn't actually random... I'm not sure the coders here would want to contribute to a deceptive marketing utility.

Comment: Hey @Number1SuperGuy, it's only random for now. Once I get this to play, I'm going to communicate with the db for an accurate number.

Comment: @Juhana, thanks I forgot to remove that from the screen. The only css relevant to this is .viewer is left: -280px; (hiding it from the screen)